# A web scraper that recursively grabs all links on a page

Tags: html, scraping, hyperlink, web

I need to obtain all the links present in a group of web pages.

Most of these pages are part of four websites, but some of these sites are not `domain.com` but rather `domain.com/~site`. Some of these pages have non-canonical duplicate URLs *that don't redirect to the canonical one*.

I want a software that runs (preferibly) on Linux or Windows, that I can provide a list of URLs, and it will generate a single, deduplicated, recursive list of all links it finds.

I've tried HTTrack but couldn't get it to behave as I need.

It would be great if it could follow HTTP redirects, JS redirects and HTML redirects (`META http-equiv="refresh"`).

### Clarification

I need a tool that will look at an URL and generate a text list of all links found (without downloading the pages). And then do that recursively.

Is there such a tool?

Comment: you can tinker with scrapy